# Neutral wire existence / problem?

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

I am replacing an old 3 way switch and am trying to figure out why my new smart switch is only turning on when the Line switch (the one that always has power) is in the up position.

Does it have something to do with the neutral on the Load switch?

(Line switch has neutral disconnected from switch) [image]

(Load) switch I replaced: [image]

Comment: Line and Load is not really used in this context.  Typically, 3-way circuits *dictate to you* where the smart switch must be; you don't get to choose.

Comment: What is the make/model of the new switch?

Comment: It's a Feit smart dimmer, instructions are here (I'm doing the one where I keep it with a regular switch)See step 6 here: help.feit.com/hc/en-us/articles/… "Install the Smart Dimmer in the location connected to the fixture, or the load."

Comment: The web page instructions are too minimalist to make any sense. The downloadable PDF is better, though not perfect. Key question for you, since the pictures are not super clear: Can you identify for switch box 1 and switch box 2: For each cable that has at least one wire going to a switch, what color(s) wires are going to which screw(s) on the switch and what color(s), if any, are going elsewhere (and where - capped separately, connected to other wires, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My wonderful answer below is a general answer for 3-way switches, colored wires, etc. But it turns out this particular smart switch has very specific instructions. Followed 100% exactly I suspect everything will work:

Based on a comment, this is a [Feit switch with instructions available online](https://www.feit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Smart_Dimmer_Installation_Guide.pdf). Based on the instructions:

- Instead of two travelers (traditional 3-way switch connection), only one traveler is used, and it is merely a signal.
- Power is sent by retasking the other traveler. The original switch then either sends or doesn't send power over the traveler, and the switch monitors that to determine when you flipped the switch.

But the instructions leave something to be desired. So here is my take on what to do:

- In the Switch 1 box, disconnect and identify (based on color) one of the traveler wires. This wire will carry power to the smart switch. Mark it with black tape if it is not a black wire. This will be referred to as *T1*.
- Disconnect the incoming hot wire from the common screw on Switch 1. This wire should be black - if it is not, **STOP**.
- Attach a short black wire (pigtail) with a wire nut to T1 and the incoming hot wire. Attach the other end of the pigtail to the common wire on Switch 1.
- Leave the second traveler attached to Switch 1. Mark it with yellow tape. This will be referred as *T2*.
- In Switch 2 box, find the *Load* wire (should be black) going to the light. Put a piece of red tape on it. Attach it to "Load" on the new switch.
- Identify the two traveler wires (must be together in one cable, same colors as they are in box 1). Put black tape (if not black insulation) on T1. Put yellow tape on T2. The insulation + tape color combinations *must* be the same as in box 1 - if not, something is wrong.
- Attach T1 to AC-L on the new switch. This is incoming power ("Line") to the switch.
- Attach T2 to YL/RD on the new switch. This is the signal wire.

The final wire is *neutral* to AC-N on the new switch. This is where I believe the instructions are totally messed up. The instructions show the two travelers (plus ground) *by themselves* traveling from box 1 to box 2. That is wrong as a balancing current must be in the same cable - either neutral (panel to 1 to 2 to light) or switched hot (2 going back to 1 to light) or hot (panel to 1 to 2 and possibly on to elsewhere). The instructions show a *separate* capped black (presumably hot) and white neutral. But that's wrong as without a functioning hot (or switched hot) the neutral is not balanced. Plain and simple **messed up**.

That being said, there are multiple ways to wire the original (pre-smart) 3-way switches, so one diagram won't easily show them all. In this particular case, it appears you have a single neutral in box 2 and a bundle of neutrals in box 1. That actually doesn't quite make sense either, but there is a possibility it may be correct. If that is actually the neutral wire, then it should be attached to the AC-N on the new switch. If it is actually *more than one* white wire together, then you add a pigtail to the bundle (might need a larger wire nut) and connect that to AC-N.

---

*Original answer:*

My new mantra - repeat after me:

**WHITE IS NOT NEUTRAL!**

But actually, that is only part of the problem here.

A smart switch needs power. At a minimum, that means *always hot* plus some return path (neutral, ground (in limited circumstances) or leaking through the load (not recommended these days because of LED lighting).

So the gold standard is **hot** + **neutral**.

When you have a pair of 3-way switches, the first one has hot + 2 travelers. So if neutral is available (same circuit, same box) then you are all set to install a smart switch.

The second switch has 2 travelers + *switched hot* (a.k.a., *load*). So you can't put a smart switch there, even if you have neutral (you might or might not, depending on other factors) because you don't have *hot*.

So right away, that means you will find it *easier* to install the smart switch as the first switch instead of the second switch.

But that isn't the end of the story. Many smart switches designed as 3-way switches only need **one traveler**. If that's the case, the second "traveler" can be used to carry *hot* to the second switch location. Of course, if the second switch location doesn't have neutral then you are still out of luck. In your case, it looks like you do have neutral in the second switch location. More details will depend on the specific make/model of smart switch.

Now back to *white is not neutral*. In a perfect world, every color would mean something. In a typical house, you may find:

- Hot/Line
- Switched Hot/Load
- Neutral
- Ground
- Travelers
- 240V circuits with *two* hots

but the usual cables are black/white/bare and black/red/white/bare. More things than colors. Bare (or green or green/yellow) is always ground. And ground is always bare or green or green/yellow. No ifs, ands or buts. But after that, it gets a little crazy.

For use with *cables only* (conduit is different):

- Hot/Line - black or red, but white under limited circumstances (e.g., switch loops)
- Switched Hot/Load - black or red
- Neutral - white. Neutral can't be black or red. But remember, white is not (necessarily) neutral.
- Ground - bare
- Travelers - black, red or white. Yes, that confuses things.
- 240V circuits with *two* hots - black and white. Unless they are actually 240V/120V circuits with a neutral included (e.g., clothes dryer) in which case the hots are black and red and the neutral is white.

Enter, the *Harper method*™. Use colors to indicate function by putting tape on the wires *when the color doesn't match the insulation*.

- Always hot (load) = black
- Switched hot = red
- Travelers = yellow (they are functionally the same, so you can use the same color for both)
- Neutral = white *but never needs tape - if it needs tape, something is very wrong!*
- Ground = bare - tape not allowed!
- 240V = black and red for hots (so tape the second hot if necessary).

So you figure out *which* blacks are switched hot and travelers and change them. You figure out *which* whites are hot, switched hot and travelers and change them. Then when you look at the switches and devices and wires it becomes very clear what is going on.

Comment: "the Harper method™" LOL didn't know he trademarked; he deserves royalties...

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed answer! I totally agree it somehow needs dedicated power to remain on but the instructions specifically state not to install it at the main (from the panel) switch, to put it on the 2nd switch.  See step 6 here: https://help.feit.com/hc/en-us/articles/4424996818583-How-to-install-and-wire-your-Feit-Electric-smart-dimmer "Install the Smart Dimmer in the location connected to the fixture, or the load."

Comment: I'm a little lost about what my next steps here should be. What do you recommend?

Comment: Thanks for the next steps! I'll try this tonight and let you know how it goes. Super appreciate your help!

Comment: This is actually a little complicated, I'll try and draw this out tomorrow. Really excited for the clear steps, thanks again!

Comment: Drew out how I understood your answer, going to try it out! https://imgur.com/a/6Z6WXzw

Comment: One key correction to your diagram (to match my text and the diagram in the manual): T1 does *not* connect to switch 1. It is a wire that originally connected to the switch but you disconnect it from the switch.

Comment: Apologies for the long list of comments! Unfortunately using T2 as a signal didn't work—whereas before switch 2 lost power when switch 1 was switched, now it remains on consistently (which is an improvement!) no matter the position of switch 1.

Comment: Upload pictures showing the new wiring on both switches

Comment: Pictures from a different circuit but set up the same way. https://imgur.com/a/Lc59RBG, I think I followed the diagram exactly. In this switch the power also stays on the dimmer which is better than it losing power but the master switch doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: Upload pictures **FROM THIS CIRCUIT SHOWING EXACTLY WHAT YOU'VE GOT**. "set up the same way" is absolutely FALSE - if they were exactly the same the results would be the same.

Comment: Sorry! They seem to be behaving the same way to me. These are from the exact same circuit we've been discussing https://imgur.com/a/SDeqtBL . If it's any help I can go into the attic to get pics of what's up there. Please let me know if there's an angle I missed!  Really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Major update, I swapped out the switch for a different switch (exact same brand, model, package) and its working! I'm going to try swapping out the one in the other room which seems to be set up the same way and see what happens.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1-first switch had a manufacturing defect, 2-one of the first attempts was wrong in a way that it killed the switch. I suspect #2. To be b honest though, if that's the case you're probably not the first one to do that. The instructions are unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: So I think wiring incorrectly without the pigtail 'broke' the switch and prevented them from using the signal correctly. I replaced another switch and it worked too. Thank you SO much for you're help! You remind me the internet has nice people!

Comment: Oh I didn't refresh earlier, yes! Number two.

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction: In some smart switch systems, one wire that would have been a traveller becomes a *signal* wire. In that setup you need compatible smart switches in both locations. Or you need to wire things so only one switch actually controls power and the second is used strictly to transmit on/off signals, then tie them together in the home automation system.

Please don't ask me why spdt smart switches are rare. They just are. Annoying.

Comment: For some reason this brand/switch (Feit smart switch) says you can use one smart dimmer with a regular 3 way switch on the other side—I think that's what I tried (in the wiring diagram here: https://imgur.com/a/6Z6WXzw but the signal doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Interesting; hadn't seen this one. They may be presuming this is a "normal" three-way circuit, where the wiring goes from first switch to second switch to controlled outlet/fixture. I'll think through what they're doing and see if I can translate it to your setup.  I'm Really Surprised that they're putting the smart switch second in the sequence rather than first.

Comment: For what it's worth, Amazon's ad for this dimmer includes a video supplied by Feit that discusses installing it as a 3-way. I presume the same video is available on Feit's own website somewhere, but meanwhile this might (or might not) help:  https://www.amazon.com/Feit-Electric-DIM-Compatible-Assistant/dp/B07SXDFH38/ref=asc_df_B07SXDFH38/

Comment: Actually, looking at those instructions I am rather confused. I can see how one could make a smart switch that provided three-way function when paired with a one-way switch on the other end, with appropriate wiring so the one-way was just providing a signal to the three-way -- but to do that you would still need the extra conductors that three-way wiring provides, since you have to provide unswitched power to the smart switch's logic. I'll look at this again when I'm more awake, but.... Weird.